# Error Message: number of query values and destination fields are not the same in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

What do you think caused the error?
It worked before I added new fields in the MS Access database, was that the cause of the error

```
    Dim conn As New 
    OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
    Source=C:\Users\JA\Documents\Sample_LogIn.accdb")
    Dim insert As String = "Insert into Students values
         ('" & textID.Text & "', " &
            "'" & textFirstName.Text & "', " &
            "'" & textLastName.Text & "', " &
            "'" & textPassword.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(insert, conn)
    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Successfully created new account.")
    Me.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error encountered while creating new account." & vbCrLf & 
              "Ërror: " & ex.Message)
```

Comment: If you don't specify the name of the columns after the INSERT INTO you are required to provide all the values for all the fields in your table.

Comment: Consider also to switch as soon as possible to use a parameterized query. In Access it is more difficult to be the target of Sql Injection but what happen if your textbox for the lastname contains a single quote? IE lastname=O'Brian